# Managed DirectX as prerequisites

Tags: installation, bootstrapper, managed-directx

I am packaging an vb.net application which uses managed DirectX and I am not using vs deployment project etc.
Now, I want to check managed directX 9 C is installed on the client or not. If not download the directX managed from the web. What is the prefered way to do this?
I found the following Microsoft Component Installer Software Development Kit, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms994369.aspx.And this the latest version I found http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=2a5e4ebc-651c-40aa-9525-1810af47c317&displaylang=en
n
I am looking for something (bootstrapper) which detect if managed directX is installed or not if not installed, download and install it.
Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You can just take the mdxredist.msi file from the component installer and trigger it with a normal setup app in visual studio.  You can add an msi to your setup project's Prerequisites list by following this:

[Adding Custom Prerequisites.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429(VS.80).aspx)

Then you can just right click on your setup project and go to Properties.  Click the Prerequisites button, and check your custom prerequisite in the list.